# AutoMapper Test is Failing during builds but passes in locally in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

its showing some un-mapped properties found but its working fine locally I am tried with [deployementiten] attribute as well but the problem remain same.

please give any suggestion .thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the test executed in your build environment? Does the test have any external dependencies (eg other test results)...?

Comment: No any external dependencies.But rest of the all unit and integration test is passing .

Answer (score 0):

```
I got the solution for it .Use Mapper.Reset() before every mapper.createMap() because without of reset it's work locally if your mapping is correct but when tests run on build server that time one copy went to the server.and mapper class is static so its taking old reference or cache the classes that's why its shoing unmapped members were found. for remove that problem is better to use mapper.reset() before mapper.createmap() its always free the all reference from the mapper class
```